# wso2 6.6.0 ei high cpu usage on windows server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 EI 6.6.0 on a windows server. And its using 96-100% of CPU usage can any one help me with this problem? I tried increasing the JVM heap size to 2GB and still facing the same problem.